# Angular material 2 navbar to hamburger menu

Tags: html, css, material-design, angular-material2

I'm trying to use the https://material.angular.io .
Adter Bootstrap 3 I used to the simle navbars, which makes everything and you don't have to implement any logic behind them.. e.g.: they move to hamburger menu when the screen is too little for show every menu element...

I'm trying to make something like this, my currently best code:

```
<md-toolbar color="primary">
    <nav md-tab-nav-bar>
        <a md-tab-link>
           This
        </a>
        <a md-tab-link>
            Looks
         </a>
         <a md-tab-link>
            really bad
         </a>
      </nav>
  </md-toolbar>
```

I need something looks like this navbars:
https://mdbootstrap.com/components/navbar/

I know I'm really far from this, but still trying to implement it..

Unfortunately I can't use mdbootstrap, because for almost every good looking thing it needs Bootstrap 4, and I'm using bootstrap 3 in the whole project.. so the upgrade would be really painful.

Thanks for the help and comments!

Comment: Can you edit your post to show a screenshot of the navbar you're trying to emulate? There are several on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello the best solution I's to move `md-tab-nav-bar` out of `md-tab-nav-bar`. So your example will look like:

```
<md-toolbar color="primary">
  some title
</md-toolbar>
<nav md-tab-nav-bar backgroundColor="primary">
  <a md-tab-link>
    This
  </a>
  <a md-tab-link>
    Looks
  </a>
  <a md-tab-link>
    really bad
  </a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hello,
Unfortunately still looks really bad and it just doesn't callopse into a hamburger menu when the screen is little.
I know it has to have nav toggle and callopse and so... other things, but unfortunately its not working inside this structure..

Comment: Collapsing into hamburger menu requires some additional scripting. It is kind of exception for material design, that is why there is no "out of the box" working solution.

Comment: The most common scenario for material design is to have predefined "hamburger" icon in the toolbar and have associated sidebar what is going to be opened by click on the icon. Here is some [spec](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-behavior)